# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error when linking OpenCV in Xcode

Tags: xcode, opencv

I have a problem linking OpenCV in Xcode.
I installed OpenCV using brew:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
sudo brew install opencv
```

I started a new Xcode commandline project, added `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include` to library and header search path.
I also added the output of `pkg-config --libs opencv` to `other linker options`.

But when I try to compile this small sample program:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat test;
    cv::namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    cv::waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

i get the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

But I am able to compile the program on the command line using

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` prog.cpp
```

So I think the problem is the way Xcode is set up. But I am not able to determine what exactly is different between the way Xcode compiles and my commandline argument.

Does anyone know the reason for this error or has an idea what I could try to investigate the problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Xcode create a new group inside your project, right click it, choose **Add Files to *Project***, navigate to the `/usr/local/lib` folder and add the following basic libraries:

> libopencv_core.dylib, libopencv_ml.dylib, libopencv_video.dylib

In previous versions of OpenCV the library names could be:

> libcxcore.dylib, libcvaux.dylib, libcv.dylib, libhighgui.dylib,
>   libml.dylib

(The libraries may be in another path depending on the method you used to install OpenCV on your Mac.)

Edit:

The above lines should not be necessary if you are including the dynamic libraries in the linking phase as the OP explains.

Select your project, go to the **Build Settings** tab, filter by *c++ standard library*, and set this parameter to **libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)**.

Comment: This produces the same error. My libraries are named slightly different. `libopencv_core.dylib` But I do not think that is a problem. Also, should it make a difference how exactly I add them? Using the `other linker option` I tried to recreate my commandline version as best as possible. Is there some way to check whether xcode is actually using those libraries for linking?

Comment: @sietschie See my edited answer, I've added another Xcode setting that may be causing this issue.

Comment: Using `libstdc++` fixed my problem.

Comment: Cant upvote this enough - just adding the libs worked for me. Thanks! :)

Comment: even if you don't work with the highgui include "libopencv_highgui", this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: If openCV is installed via Homebrew, then the libraries should lie under `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/yourOpenCVVersion/lib`

Answer (score 7):

I've set the Build Settings -> c++ standard library to **Compiler Default**. The errors disappeared.

Comment: libstdc++ didn't work for me but compiler default did

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following libraries (build phases -> link binary with libraries) so OpenCV would build:

- Accelerate
- AssetsLibrary
- AVFoundation
- CoreGraphics
- CoreImage
- CoreMedia
- CoreVideo
- QuartzCore
- UIKit
- Foundation

Ref: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#opencviosvideoprocessing

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use opencv in xcode for iOS, and I solve the errors by using the opencv through pod install rather than offline opencv framework.

You can have a try by adding the opencv pod text below:

```
pod 'OpenCV', '2.4.9'
```