# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error in Xcode 5 in OS X Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv

Somewhat a similar problem with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078512/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-error-when-linking-opencv-in-xcode) but this only happened after I upgraded to Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.2.

I'm able to compile and run with

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` prog.cpp
```

but got linker errors when trying to run with Xcode like those found in the linked question.

I've tried many possible configurations like changing 'Library Search Path' to '/usr/local/lib' and adding directories to  'Header Search Paths' like '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/include' and '/opt/local/include'. I've also tried to all possible options in 'C++ Standard Library' like 'libstdc++', 'libc++' and 'Compiler Default'. I'm really running out of ideas as to where the problem may lie.

For the cpp file, I've simply included `<opencv2/opencv.hpp>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also suffering from this for the past couple of days. From the same post you were referencing:

> I've set the Build Settings -> c++ standard library to Compiler
>   Default. The errors disappeared.

This worked for me.