# Trouble installing Dlib

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I recently installed OpenCV 3.0 on macOS Sierra 10.12.

After I installed OpenCV I tried to [compile the Dlib examples](http://dlib.net/compile.html) following the instructions on their website. I ran into a build error here that I'm not quite sure how to fix.

The error:

```
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable webcam_face_pose_ex
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)", referenced from:
  _main in webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()", referenced from:
  _main in webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)", referenced from:
  _main in webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.o
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
  _main in webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.o
  "cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
  _main in webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.o
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
  _main in webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.o
  "_IplImage::_IplImage(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
  dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel>::cv_image(cv::Mat) in webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const", referenced from:
  _main in webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [webcam_face_pose_ex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/webcam_face_pose_ex.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I realize these are linker errors. Would someone be so kind as to tell me how to fix these linker errors?

Comment: Does your CMakeLists.txt include find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED ) and target_link_libraries( YourProgram ${OpenCV_LIBS} )?

Comment: I opened it up in vim and searched for 'find_package'. The argument for find_package() with OpenCV was find_package(OpenCV QUIET). Should I change it?

Comment: I changed QUIET to REQUIRED and the same error occurred.

Comment: And also target_link_libraries( YourProgram ${OpenCV_LIBS} ) exists right?

Comment: I searched a bit, think that this answer(http://stackoverflow.com/a/16078903/3244341) can solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, target_link_libraries was there. I should point out that I am not building this with XCode. I am building the examples that come with the downloaded file from the Dlib website itself. I am building these examples with cmake in the command line.

Comment: I don't see any connection to `cuda`.  Removing tag.